Possibly closed set in infinite product topology
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find whether the set $A = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} [0,\infty)$ is a closed or an open set in the two infinite product topologies of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$:

$\tau_{box}$, which consists on basic open sets of the form $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} U_i$, with $U_i$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.
$\tau_{product}$, which consists on basic open sets of the form $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i$, with $A_i = \mathbb{R}$ with the exception of finite number of indices, which are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ but not the whole space.

In my case, I think that in both topologies the set is closed since $[0,\infty)$ it is in real numbers with the usual topology, but I find it so easy that I'm also under the suspect that in might be wrong. With respect to whether it is open or not, I would say that it isn't in neither of both topologies. Which is the real answer? Is an infinite product of closed sets a closed set in any of the product topologies?

remember that a closed set is the complement of an open set

"Is an infinite product of closed sets a closed set in any of the product topologies?" Yes, arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed in any topological space.

Notice that we can write $A$ as
$$A=\{(a_n)_{n\geq1}: \forall n ,a_n\geq0\}$$
And so
$$A^c = \bigcup_{i\geq1}\{(a_n)_{n\geq1}: a_i<0\}=\bigcup_{i\geq1}\prod_{j\geq 1} U_j^i$$
Where
$$U_j^i=\begin{cases}(-\infty,0)&\text{if }i=j\\\\\mathbb R&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Therefore, in either topology, $A^c$ is a union of open sets, and therefore open, and so $A$ must be closed in both topologies

So $A$ is the set of sequences of non-negative real numbers.  So the complement of $A$ is the set of sequences that have one or more negative numbers.  So there can be more than one $i$ (in fact infinitely many $i$s) for a given element of $A^c$ with $a_i\lt0$, right?

@J.W.Tanner Yes! But for certain it has at least one, that's what the union is doing. If some guy it's on the complement of $A$ then it has some negative coordinate. I'm classifying them in terms of which coordinates are negative. This is most certainly not a disjoint union, for instance the constant sequence $-1$ is in all the sets

To check my understanding:  the set of sequences of  negative (or of strictly positive) real numbers is open in the box topology but not in the product topology, but the set of sequences with say the fifth entry negative and other entries unrestricted is open in both of those topologies

and you are taking the union of the latter where $i$ can be any natural number, not just $5$, and that union is open (since it’s a union of open sets)

@J.W.Tanner exactly!

Thank you (+1) for helping me brush up on this topic — I remember learning it in Munkres’ book years ago but I am quite rusty now — and for correcting my erroneous answer (I was thinking the complement of sequences with non-negative entries would be sequences with all negative entries, but obviously that’s wrong because sequences with some negative entries must also be included)

@J.W.Tanner No problem! Always happy to help!

It has been a time ago since I asked the questio, but I just realised I didn't get (or at least I haven't read) one part of the answer. Is it an open set in any of the topologies? I think it isn't. Is this true?
